# Salesforce Files Vs Salesforce CRM Content

Tags: content, files, libraries

Which one is the future? Or shall they continue to coexist? Can there be a scenario where both features are recommended to be used in tandem or interchangeably?

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope it is acceptable now.

Answer (score 5):

Hope you have gone through these differences before posting the question.

Refer [Differences Between Files, Salesforce CRM Content, Salesforce Knowledge, Documents, and Attachments](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_differences.htm&type=0)

[image: File vs CRM Content]

CRM Content needs separate licenses (Salesforce CRM Content User) where as using files do not need separate licenses.

CRM Content gives much more security and flexibility which Files doesn't provide that. Those uploaded files can be used for CRM content.

Mainly, it contributes how you deliver the content, you can put expiration date, password protection, downloadable URL for external users which cannot be possible without CRM Content.

Chatter Free users can use Chatter files which has been uploaded in chatter. External customers can see the files (if they join in private chatter group) and if the files have shared publicly.

Also, refer [Salesforce CRM Content Implementation Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_content_implementation_guide.pdf) to know more details.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am not sure how I can like your comment. PS: I went through the "Differences" doc in Salesforce Help before posting this question.

Comment: If my answer serves your purpose then accept this, so that others may find this useful

Comment: My question is on hold, although I have edited and shortened it. Doesn't show me an Accept button or link at present.

Comment: Looking at the last couple of releases, I would say that Files is the way to go. Content doesn't seem to be moving towards Lightning whereas Files are getting new features. For example: extended security like Private files (which can be shared).