# Share files publicly via Saleforce Files

Tags: files

### BACKGROUND

We are now deciding if storing files inside Salesforce would give us any benefit comparing to 3rd party providers. The main requirements are (1) allow big files (up to 1 GB); (2) Allow for public sharing (namely generate download links) so that external users can download files.

Question #1 is clear, but point #2 is quite a mystery for me. Follow me further.

From this question [Salesforce Files Vs Salesforce CRM Content](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185002/salesforce-files-vs-salesforce-crm-content) I got understanding that Content Deliveries allow Files to be shared with external users who don't have access to Salesforce (public links, password protection, expiry etc.) I also studied official docs [Differences Between Files, Salesforce CRM Content, Salesforce Knowledge, Documents, and Attachments](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_differences.htm&type=5), [Salesforce Files](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collaboration_admin_files.htm&type=5) and [Salesforce CRM Content](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_admin_crm_content.htm&type=5), but still have an impression that I am missing something about public sharing. Is Content Delivery is the only option to share files (I don't count Chatter files for this question)?

The reason I am asking this is when I created a user (profile: Standard User) without a "Salesforce CRM Content User" license and logged into the system as this user, I was able to upload a file as File associated with Account. All this was done in my Developer edition org.

[image]

And then I managed to share this file publicly by creating a public link, which my colleague could open and download the file successfully. NOTE, she didn't have access to my Dev org.

[image]

### QUESTION

Does it mean that we can share files with external users just with Salesforce Files? Are there any implications or hidden "traps"? And for this neither the "Salesforce CRM Content User" license nor Content Deliveries are necessary (as long as we don't need some flexible behavior for shared files, like password protection).

Comment: The [**answer**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/185009/54851) on the question that you have referred in here provides your answers too -- [*CRM Content needs separate licenses (Salesforce CRM Content User) where as using files do not need separate licenses.*]

Comment: Thanks @JayantDas. My main confusion was that both Files and Content Deliveries (CD) provide possibility to create public links, i.e. share files externally with users who don't have access to a Salesforce org. Previously, I thought that only CD allows that, and SF Files don't. The answer and official docs don't explain public sharing in detail.